# how many times the character in the array b changes by observing the elements from the beginning

Tags: java, arrays, counting

```
public static  int changeSign(int [] b) {

    int counter=0 ;

    for(int i=0;i<b.length;i++) {

        if(b[i]>0 && b[i+1]<0) {

            counter++;

        }
        if(b[i]<0 && b[i+1]>0) {

            counter++;

        }

    }

    return counter;
    }
```

For example, `u 10, -4, 12, 56, -8, -9`, the character changes `3` times

Comment: Sorry in an Array not string

Comment: Do you mean the sign `+`, `-` changes ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. As explained in the tour, this site is a repository of useful questions and their answers.Please see how to create a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example that demonstrates your problem. Please take the tour at https://stackoverflow.com/tour , visit the https://stackoverflow.com/help and especially read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to learn how to use this site effectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you got is `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` because when `i` is `b.length-1` you try to access `b[i+1]` which is `b[b.length]` and this is not possible as indexing starts at 0, so you need to stop one step before.

---

Also to get only one condition, you can multiply and look at the sign of the result :

```
public static int changeSign(int[] b) {
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < b.length - 1; i++) {
        if (b[i] * b[i + 1] < 0) {
            counter++;
        }
    }
    return counter;
}
```